# share authentication between 2 Grails apps

Tags: authentication, grails, oauth

I'm developing 2 Grails applications - A and B - and I would like to support the following use cases

1. If a user has an account with A, they may also use it to register/login to B (in much the same way as you can use Twitter, Google, etc. credentials to register/login to http://stackoverflow.com). Similarly, if a user has an account with B, it can be used to register/login to A.
2. Users also have the option to use separate accounts on each site, i.e. they are not *forced* to use their A credentials on B (or vice versa)
3. If a user has used their A credentials to authenticate to B (or vice versa) this establishes trust between the 2 sites, allowing A to call an API of B's to retrieve additional information about the user. There needs to be a mechanism that ensures the API can only be called for users that have agreed to share authentication data between the two sites.

Ideally I'd like to use a standards-based approach, e.g. by making each site an OAuth consumer/provider, but I'm not sure which standards are the most relevant standards. If there are any plugins that would help me implement a solution, that would also be useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com) is exactly what you need:

- User management API with different SDKs: node.js, express, java, rest, python, flask.
- Off the shelf Hosted Login: login, registration, and password reset.
- Off the shelf ID Site to power Single Sign-On across your applications
- API keys for your users, secured with HTTP Basic Auth or OAuth2
- Social Login: Facebook, Google, LinkedIn, Github
- Integration with Shiro and Spring Security
- Integration with Active Directory and LDAP

In bullet number 3, you are talking about [SSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on). You can achieve that with Stormpath and Shiro. Please [read here](https://support.stormpath.com/hc/en-us/articles/203815036-Can-I-SSO-between-multiple-Wars-in-the-same-servlet-with-Stormpath-and-Apache-Shiro-).

Disclaimer, I am an Stormpath contributor.